# Submitting Recaptcha v2 with selenium when no submit button is present python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, automation, recaptcha

I am using services of [ImageTyperz](http://www.imagetyperz.com/) for solving the captcha but unable to submit a response back to the website. There is no submit button but a callback is there which should be called. When i call this callback i get **selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: script timeout** exception.
The function which is called looks like this

> 

```
                    function solvedCaptcha(payload) {
                        const timeoutMs = 10000;
                        protectionSubmitCaptcha("recaptcha", payload, timeoutMs, "3:wi5qRb7c93CuT63y1uUslQ==:BXJXyJOzlEFA5FdRRQw7hUgzO5M4FIz8DegFPzs6fER0MRWYM+P2Vac+z3qKo5UxmDqMuThgGaT0hK+Tu6Zj0b5sprMSQI7P2Wv7fAj7aFUC20NO7VN6NtyyTehmQcxscyQBUqvlXbyTct2rUi81hPRk9fp7Vt32kGZspgx0v4tbTmDK2xMG1mj5nOVN9TL5zs88iYQDfSa2lKcdLrhYl5VcEDh5rAAte8d6rvead+5oY0a8B7fennPu2+36wZboyg4JJ1yMSpMmZ8Nk47/R/Q==:BwSP9POMwcERVjmiYuOpMZkDQmQS1ksQSij5jk8Fs8A=").then(function() {
                            window.location.reload(true);
                        });
                    }
```

I am running the following command

> driver.execute_async_script("var payload = " + str(recaptcha_response) + ";" + "solvedCaptcha(payload);")

Here recaptcha_response is the response dict got from ImageTyperz api.

Comment: You want regular `execute_script` here. Otherwise it times out waiting for a callback.

Comment: @pguardiario It worked, Thanks alot. Now the problem is that the website is still not opened and it looks like nothing happened in the backend. The selenium webdriver is still at captcha page. Shouldn't it move forward and go to the main page instead of captcha page?

Comment: I can't tell from that. Usually there's a textarea that you fill with the captcha data

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem

I've finally managed to resolve this myself. In case anyone else is struggling with a similar issue, here was my solution:

- Open the console and execute the following cmd: ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients
- Find the path which has the callback function, in my case it's ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].O.O
- Use the following code: driver.execute_script(f"___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].O.O.callback('{new_token}')") (Remember to change the path accordingly)

This [Article](https://discourse.openbullet.dev/t/guide-recaptcha-v2-bypass-and-callbacks/3252) will help you to find the ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients of your recaptcha site

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "{}";'.format(g_response))   
driver.execute_script(f"___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].O.O.callback('{g_response}')")
```